# Why did Israel vote against lifting the American embargo on Cuba?

Tags: united-states, united-nations, israel, cuba

Every single country in the world except for the United States and Israel voted for the United States to end the embargo on Cuba.

[image]

My question is, why Israel? Many of the nations on this list are allies of the US, but why does only Israel support the embargo? What does Israel hope to get from this?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Many countries consider themselves allies of the US, but few take foreign policy stances just because the US says so. (The US also does not always vote the same way as its allies.) The vast majority of the world consider the US embargo to be an act of revenge driven by the interests of Cuban Americans, and others who had property confiscated at the time of the revolution, and consider it completely unjustified as a matter of foreign policy, so they vote against it.

Israel as a country is absolutely indebted to the US. The US is virtually the only country not condemning at least some of its actions in Palestine, and continuing to supply it with extensive military and civil aid without conditions. Without continued support from the US Israel (or at least its present policies) would be in severe trouble.

Israel therefore, when asked to take an action that doesn't really inconvenience it much, votes with the United States. It isn't in a position to disagree with the US on foreign policy.

Comment: *"driven by the interests of Cuban Americans"*, can you elaborate on that? I (and many others, I think) aren't that familiar with US-Cuban relations (at least on a human level) to know what interests you mean. A simple link to an (opinion) article would suffice.

Comment: Cuban Americans are largely (not exclusively) wealthy Cubans who fled the Cuban revolution, or their descendants. They want to be restored to the positions of power and wealth they had before, especially to have the property that was confiscated from them after they fled returned.

Comment: I see, but I'm still not sure how the embargo helps with that. If you think it's too complicated to answer here, perhaps there will be a different question dedicated to that later on.

Comment: @JJJ At least in theory, the point of the embargo is to bring down the government of Cuba and get a new government, one that will be willing to respect the property claims of the Cuban Americans.

Comment: *Cuban Americans are largely (not exclusively) wealthy Cubans who fled the Cuban revolution*. False. And, as another answer stated, Israel has other strong reasons to vote against the current Cuban regime.

Comment: You're conflating two things, I think. The US embargo continues because of unaddressed claims on American property in Cuba, not Cuban Americans. Also, according to [Pew](https://www.pewhispanic.org/2015/09/15/hispanics-of-cuban-origin-in-the-united-states-2013/), more than half of the Cuban Americans in the US are foreign born, not the rich who left shortly after the revolution.

Comment: Cuban Americans represent 0.58% of the US population, and only slightly more of the US government. That's smaller than Jews, Muslims, and various other small groups. It's much smaller than the number of Puerto Ricans (who admittedly can't vote in general elections). I won't say that Cuban-American lobbying has no effect, because some research has found statistically significant effects. But I think it's likely not enough to explain US policy by itself. I think that opposition to the Soviet Union, and latter Communist countries in general, might have been a larger contributor.

Comment: One might suppose that Cubans would have disproportionate political influence due to being wealthier on average. But [according to polls](https://www.pewhispanic.org/2015/09/15/hispanics-of-cuban-origin-in-the-united-states-2013/), the average (median) Cuban American household income is only $5,000 more than the median income overall, and foreign-Cuban Americans actually have a median income $5,000 lower.

Comment: @Obie2.0 that analysis ignores how vital regional votes can be in the US, you would have to look specifically at Floridian constituencies as that is where Cuban immigrants mostly settled and had the largest effect on politics. Further, you can't just look at current statistics, but have to think about how much things are skewed because the first big wave of Cuban immigrants was in large part wealthy people fleeing after the revolution. They were also willing to use violence to further their goals, see Luis Posada Carriles

Comment: There's also obviously some bias in recent Cuban immigrants - the most ardent lovers of the post-revolutionary system are more likely to endure the problems there, and the ones who are either ambivalent or opposed for whatever reason are more likely to head to the US, which makes immigration easy for them in order to undermine the Cuban government

Comment: @llama - Good point about regional votes. After all, higher Cuban-American turnout helped Reagan win Florida in 1980. As for wealth, I didn't elaborate on this, but those "wealthy" people almost certainly didn't retain a large part of their wealth, precisely because it was confiscated by the Cuban government. Certainly compared to populations that had lived in the US for a long time, I wouldn't expect them to have wealth disproportionate to their income.

Comment: There is simply a far more obvious primary  explanation than Cuban lobbying. Castro quickly aligned himself with the Soviet Union, the main competitor of the US. He also nationalized *American* agricultural, financial, and energy interests. People opposed to Communism constituted a significant proportion of the US population, and wealthy business owners actually *were* wealthy.

Comment: If we look at the history of the Cuba embargo, it mainly  dates back to 1962, with the arms sale ban dating to even before Castro. This was long before Cuban-Americans helped carry Reagan to victory in Florida, but it was right after the expropriation of US businesses and property.

Comment: @Obie2.0 You don't see the US embargoing other countries that supported the USSR.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Most of those countries weren't 103 miles from the US and didn't expropriate the property of American companies. And the Korean and especially Vietnam wars definitely showed that the US was willing to go much further than embargoes with countries aligned with the USSR, even ones that were far away.

Comment: The US was always much more worried about Cuba than anywhere else due to its proximity, rationally or otherwise. Thus the Cuban missile crisis.

Answer (score 58):

I'm not even sure in what year that vote you mention was taken, because it's a UN tradition [by now](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_embargo_against_Cuba)

> The UN General Assembly has, since 1992, passed a resolution every year condemning the ongoing impact of the embargo and declaring it in violation of the Charter of the United Nations and of international law. In 2014, out of the 193-nation assembly, 188 countries voted for the nonbinding resolution, the United States and Israel voted against and the Pacific Island nations Palau, Marshall Islands and Micronesia abstained.

Israel has also been on the receiving end of numerous resolutions at the UN. In the Security Council, the US [has vetoed numerous such resolutions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/40270/which-country-benefited-the-most-from-un-security-council-vetoes).

It's not surprising to see Israel reciprocate how it can on an issue the US cares about.

Comment: The image is dated 2017

Answer (score 51):

Other answers focus on the US-Israeli relationship, but there is also no love lost between Cuba and Israel. Cuba sent troops to fight Israel in the Yom Kippur War after breaking relations the previous month; neither side chose to restore formal relations. Cuba continued supporting Palestinian guerrillas (like the PLO) until the collapse of the Soviet bloc.

One [source](https://militaryhistorynow.com/2020/10/23/the-cuban-army-abroad-fidel-castros-forgotten-foreign-wars-2/), though it's readily found with Google.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer.

Comment: This so far the most logical answer

Comment: It's somewhat logical, but I doubt it's the real answer you would get if an Israeli diplomat was explaining things honestly. Israel has much more to gain from staying in lockstep with the US than continuing to hold a grudge against Cuba for events from more than 30 years ago

Comment: @llama The real answer is no doubt more complex and I don't pretend to present the absolute answer, but you are wrong that it's merely a grudge. Cuba supplied the PLO until 1991, when the money dried up, and Raul Castro was the man in charge of the Cuban Army during the Yom Kippur War; he only stepped down as Presdent last year and still serves as First Secretary.

Comment: For comparison, the Koreas and the US have held a grudge since 1953. Spain has held a grudge against the UK over Gibraltar since 1953. Saudi Arabia is still nursing Wahhabism, which emerged in 1930, to stick it to non-fundamentalist and non-Sunni Muslims. Disputes last a long time with nations devoted to continual revolution and/or territorial integrity, especially family-run autocracies completely convinced of their own political theories.

Comment: Another source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuba%E2%80%93Israel_relations)